# What is the time complexity of a function that generates combinations of length r from n elements without repetitions or permutations?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The following function takes in a list of elements *src* as well as a combination length *r*. It prints out all possible combinations of length r, without repetition of an element inside a combination or repetition of a combination in a different order (permutation).

```
  void fn(List<dynamic> src, int r, List<dynamic> tmp) {
    for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
      tmp.add(src.removeAt(i));
      
      if (tmp.length == r) print(tmp.toString());
      
      else if (i < src.length) fn(src.sublist(i), r, tmp);
      
      src.insert(i, tmp.removeLast());
    }
  }
```

So, given n = [1,2,3,4,5] and r = 3, it would print out

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
```

How would you describe the time complexity of this function in Big O notation? Clearly both the length of *src* as well as *r* have to be taken into account. If I am not mistaken, the time complexity of a similar function printing out all combinations **with repetitions and permutations** would be O(n^r). But what is it in this case?

Comment: It looks like your code prints all combinations, and takes time proportional to the length of a combination to print that combination. So the complexity has to be (length of a combination) * (number of combinations).

Comment: The length of a combination is r, and the number of combinations is (length(src) choose r). See [Wikipedia: (n choose k)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

According to Stef's comment, the time complexity seems to be **O(r(n choose r))**.